# How do I convert a post request from request js to got js that contains a stream parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, requestjs, node.js-got

I am migrating a library from [request](https://github.com/request/request) to [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) and am getting stuck with a specific type of post request. The endpoint looks for a specific body which contains a filename and a stream of the file being uploaded. I have been unable to get this working in the *got* library and am now seeking assistance.

Below are the code snippets or here is a [link to a repl.it version](https://repl.it/@Awhiteweb/OutrageousOblongSeptagon)

Here is the working call in *request*:

```
/**
 * @param {string} uri 
 * @param {string} filename 
 * @param {stream} body file stream
 * @param {string} token
 * @returns {Promise<string>}
 */
async function uploadFile(uri, filename, body, token) {
  return await request({
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `OAuth2 ${token}`,
      ["Content-Type"]: "multipart/form-data"
    },
    formData: {
      source: body,
      filename
    },
    method: "POST",
    uri
  });
}
```

Here are my unsuccessful tests using *got*:

```
/**
 * @param {string} uri 
 * @param {string} filename 
 * @param {stream} body file stream
 * @param {string} token
 * @returns {Promise<string>}
 */
async function uploadFileTest1(uri, filename, body, token) {
  return await got(uri, {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `OAuth2 ${token}`,
      ["Content-Type"]: "multipart/form-data"
    },
    form: {
      source: body,
      filename
    },
    method: "POST"
  });
}

/**
 * @param {string} uri 
 * @param {string} filename 
 * @param {stream} body file stream
 * @param {string} token
 * @returns {Promise<void>}
 */
async function uploadFileTest2(uri, filename, body, token) {
  const chunks = [];
  const pipeline = promisify(Stream.pipeline);
  await pipeline(
    body,
    got.stream.post(uri, {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: `OAuth2 ${token}`,
        ["Content-Type"]: "multipart/form-data"
      },
      form: {
        source: body,
        filename
      },
      method: "POST",
      isStream: true
    })
  ).catch(err => console.error(err.message));
}

/**
 * @param {string} uri 
 * @param {string} filename 
 * @param {stream} body file stream
 * @param {string} token
 * @returns {Promise<string>}
 */
async function uploadFileTest3(uri, filename, body, token) {
  const chunks = [];
  const pipeline = promisify(Stream.pipeline);
  const responseStream = new Stream.Duplex();
  await pipeline(
    body,
    got.stream.post(uri, {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: `OAuth2 ${token}`,
        ["Content-Type"]: "multipart/form-data"
      },
      form: {
        source: body,
        filename
      },
      method: "POST",
      isStream: true
    }),
    responseStream
  );
  return await new Promise((res, rej) => {
    responseStream.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk));
    responseStream.on('error', rej);
    responseStream.on('end', () => res(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8')));
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err.message, err.stack);
    throw new Error(err.message);
  });
}

/**
 * @param {string} uri 
 * @param {string} filename 
 * @param {stream} body file stream
 * @param {string} token
 * @returns {Promise<string>}
 */
async function uploadFileTest4(uri, filename, body, token) {
  const chunks = [];
  const pipeline = promisify(Stream.pipeline);
  const responseStream = new Stream.Duplex();
  await pipeline(
    got.stream.post(uri, {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: `OAuth2 ${token}`,
        ["Content-Type"]: "multipart/form-data"
      },
      form: {
        source: body,
        filename
      },
      method: "POST",
      isStream: true
    }),
    responseStream
  );
  return await new Promise((res, rej) => {
    responseStream.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk));
    responseStream.on('error', rej);
    responseStream.on('end', () => res(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8')));
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err.message, err.stack);
    throw new Error(err.message);
  });
}
```

Here is the request from https://postman-echo.com service:

```
{
  "args": {},
  "data": {},
  "files": {
    "test.txt": "data:application/octet-stream;base64,dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QgZG9jdW1lbnQ="
  },
  "form": {
    "filename": "text.txt"
  },
  "headers": {
    "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
    "x-forwarded-port": "443",
    "host": "postman-echo.com",
    "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-5fad9989-0acbc1e97ad72aa26855df7b",
    "content-length": "346",
    "accept": "application/json",
    "authorization": "OAuth2 abc",
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------347114605132179681480756"
  },
  "json": null,
  "url": "https://postman-echo.com/post"
}
```

Comment: Can you add full headers of both requests?

Comment: And a piece of body as well

Comment: @Anatoly I only have the headers and body listed above in the request object. I have made an edit to the question to show the request as echoed by the postman service

Comment: Can you catch both requests from `reqeust` and `got` by using something like Fiddler (on Windows) or other somilar utility (on Linux)?

Comment: You ddin't use `form-data` pacakge to indicate form data in body.